# CommunityToolkit.Maui Popup fullscreen throws error

Tags: popup, maui-community-toolkit

We have a MAUI app. Our primary target is Windows (and not actively running on Android or iOS).

Our app uses a FlyoutPage anchored left side of screen (a navbar). Our app only runs full screen.

We wanted to create a popup that would be essentially a cameraview and have it run full screen). Tried setting Size property but runtime exception 'System.InvalidOperationException' in CommunityToolkit.Maui.dll. Anyone have a workaround?

I note there is a similar bug #1604 but was closed as not planned.